# Accessing Expressjs resources from a different port (CORS)

Tags: node.js, express, cors

I've got one development environment on localhost:3050 and another running on localhost:3000.

I've got various static files being served as mounted directories from :3050, e.g:

`app.use('/app',express.static(__dirname + '/app'));`

I've configured Access-Control-Allow-Origin so that CORS requests from :3000 to :3050 are permitted. Indeed the request goes through, but the application which is expecting to find files on http://localhost:3000, can't.

I'm aware of options of proxies or setting up an SSH - would these be a good idea for this use case?

I would have thought express should have some kind of way to adjust the domain:port location for the hosting of files - hoping I might just be missing something.

Comment: have you tried accessing the files from the browser?

Comment: Yeah, access works on :3050 but not :3000

Answer (score 0):

Try this [cors](https://github.com/expressjs/cors) package. It works magically in some cases.